# DB2: add total number of rows to each row

Tags: db2, max

I'm trying to figure out where in a CTE I get extra rows, or rows deleted, so I would like to - at one point in my CTE where I suspect there is a problem - add a column which just contain one number, namely the count of rows of the whole table.
I've tried *count()*, but it seem to want a "group by" clause, and row_number() over() just gives me number of rows, so I'm stuck here...

Comment: `count(*) over ()` should do it

Comment: That works great, thank you! If you'd make a quick answer, I could close this :) up to you! :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count()` as window function, just add:

```
count(*) over () as total_count
```

to your query.